# System.Console.Write("{0}{1:N2} {2}" what's {1:N2} referring to?

Tags: c#, .net

i know 0 is for the first element in the array etc... but what's 1:N2?

Answer (score 6):

The format to be applied to the data. In this case two decimal number.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720653(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

`{1:N2}` means that the second parameter is formatted as a number with thousand seperators and a precision of 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

The index "1" to the left of the colon specifies the second of the `arg` parameters (zero-based indexing).  The string "N2" to the right of the colon specifies the format to use on that parameter.  Specifically, N2 means group-separator numeric format with 2 decimal places; for details, see the documentation on standard format strings at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

In general, the format specifier is of the form `{ index[,alignment][ : formatString] }`; for details, see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttxecb1c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is Numeric formatting the second element. Formatting in .Net can be done on different data types like number, dates, enums. you can also create custom formats. you can get started on formatting here
[Formatting Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Not the third, the second element ;-)